# Add dataframe to a nested list in a nested for-loop, as in: listname[[xx]][yy] <- value

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, nested-lists

I have a nested loop during which I want to add dataframes into a list, as in:

```
listname <- list()

for(xx in 1:50) {

   listname[[xx]] <- list()

   for(yy in 1:25) {

      my_df <- data.frame(aa = c(1,2,".."), bb = c(1,2,".."))

      listname[[xx]][yy] <- my_df

   }

}
```

However, I get the warning message:

"**number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length**"

... and as a result, only `my_df$aa` is in `listname[[xx]][yy]`, but not `my_df$bb`.

What would be a more appropriate way to accomplish a nested list of dataframes with this approach?

Thank you!

**EDIT: Found the solution!** It turns out that the only mistake was the lack of a further bracket. It should have been `listname[[xx]][[yy]] <- my_df`. Thanks to Ben in the comments; it works now.

Comment: Did you mean `listname[[xx]][[yy]] <- my_df` with double brackets for `yy`?

Comment: Oh my - I am ashamed, but you are correct, Ben. Do you want to write it as an answer so that I can 'accept' it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use double brackets `[[` for `yy` in storing your data frames as follows:

```
listname[[xx]][[yy]] <- my_df
```

The use of `[[` is important when working with lists, since subsetting a list with `[` (single bracket alone) always returns a smaller list.

To see the difference, take a look at `listname[[1]][1]`:

```
[[1]]
  aa bb
1  1  1
2  2  2
3 .. ..
```

This is a *list* returned.

Then we can compare with `listname[[1]][[1]]`:

```
  aa bb
1  1  1
2  2  2
3 .. ..
```

Which is a *data.frame*.

In this case, when you are want to replace a single value in a list with a data.frame, you will want to use `[[`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `replicate` to get such nested list of dataframes.

```
my_df <- data.frame(aa = c(1,2,".."), bb = c(1,2,".."))
listname <- replicate(50, replicate(25, 
                      my_df, simplify = FALSE), simplify = FALSE)
```